# How to replace string and exclude certain changing integers?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to replace

```
'AMAT_0000006951_10Q_20200726_Filing Section: Risk'
```

with:

```
'AMAT 10Q Filing Section: Risk'
```

However, everything up until *Filing Section: Risk* will be constantly changing, except for positioning. I just want to pull the characters from position 0 to 5 and from 15 through 19.

```
df['section'] = df['section'].str.replace(
```

I'd like to manipulate this but not sure how?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your series as `s`

```
s.str.slice(0, 5) + s.str.slice(15, 19)  # if substring-ing
s.str.replace(r'\d{5}', '')  # for a 5-length digit string
```

You may need to adjust your numbers to index properly. If that doesn't work, you probably want to use a regular expression to get rid of some length of numbers (as above, with the example of 5).

Or in a single line to produce the final output you have above:

```
s.str.replace(r'\d{10}_|\d{8}_', '').str.replace('_', ' ')
```

Though, it might not be wise to replace the underscores. Instead, if they change, explode the data into various columns which can be worked on separately.

Comment: I didn't even think about setting _ to new columns, I also wonder, would that help with TF-IDF if I'm analyzing information found in both 10-K, 8-K, 10-Q documents?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace a fix length/position of chars, use `str.slice_replace` to replace

```
df['section'] = df['section'].str.slice_replace(6, 14, ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people would probably use regex to replace pieces in your string.  However, I would:

1. Split the string
2. append the piece if it isn't a number
3. Join the remaining data

Like so:

```
s = 'AMAT_0000006951_10Q_20200726_Filing Section: Risk'
n = []

for i in s.split('_'):
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        n.append(i)

print(' '.join(n))
AMAT 10Q Filing Section: Risk
```

Edit:

Re-reading your question, if you are just looking to substring:

Grabbing the first 5 characters:

```
s = 'AMAT_0000006951_10Q_20200726_Filing Section: Risk'
print(s[:4])  # print index 0 to 4 == first 5

print(s[15:19])  # print index 15 to 19

print(s[15:])  # print index 15 to the end.
```

If you would like to just replace pieces:

```
print(s.replace('_', ' '))
```

you could throw this in one line as well:

```
print((s[:4] + s[15:19] + s[28:]).replace('_', ' '))
'AMAT 10Q Filing Section: Risk'
```

Comment: Hey, I should have been a little more clear in my post, but the object I'm looking to change is embedded in DF as section, so I will not be able to set it to a variable, all said an done I think there will be upwards of 100,000 of these strings under 'section' so was hoping for the ability to replace certain pieces of the string with just a space ' '

Comment: These functions do not apply to `pd.Series`, they apply to `str`. With some 100 000 observations, it would be faster to vectorise operations rather than looping through with `apply`.